# Angular 6 passport-facebook does not work on Heroku

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku, mean-stack, passport-facebook

I am using passport-facebook in a MEAN stack app (Angular 6). It works perfectly in dev but doesn't work in production in Heroku.

When I click the facebook button on Heroku the url briefly changes from https://example.com/#/login to https://example.com/api/user/facebook then switches back again and thats all it does. There is nothing in the Heroku logs to suggest it reached the api.

As per the [docs](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/facebook/) My login page contains a link:

```
<a href="/api/user/facebook" class="btn btn-primary">
  <span class="fa fa-facebook"></span> Facebook
</a>
```

Which consumes my api

```
router.get('/facebook', (req, res, next) => {
console.log('/facebook');
req.session.redirect = req.query.redirectUrl;
passport.authenticate('facebook')(req, res, next);
return;
```

});

Which then invokes this

```
    passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: config.facebookAuth.clientID,
    clientSecret: config.facebookAuth.clientSecret,
    callbackURL: config.facebookAuth.callbackURL
  }, (token, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
      User.findOne({
          'facebook.id': profile.id
        }, (err, user) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return done(err);
          }
          if (user) {
            return done(null, user);
          } else {
            var newUser = new User();
            newUser.facebook.id = profile.id;
            newUser.facebook.token = token;
            newUser.facebook.displayName = profile.displayName;
            newUser.save((err) => {
              done(null, newUser);
            });
          }
        }
      )
    }
  )
)
```

Which then invokes the callback

```
router.get('/facebook/callback', passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/#/login' }), (req, res) => {
    console.log('/facebook/callback');
    jwt.sign({
        user: req.user
    }, config.privateKey, { expiresIn: '1h' }, (err, token) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
        res.cookie('token', token, { maxAge: 3600000 });
        res.redirect(!!req.session.redirect ? '/#' + req.session.redirect : '/#/create');
    });
});
```

The callback url is set correctly in config and matches the one added to the facebook developers console. I cannot see anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

So after much trial error and many Google searches I discovered that Facebook will only allow requests from HTTPS. Even though my Heroku domain was HTTPS it did not have an ssl certificate. I upgraded to a hobby dyno and applied an ssl cert in the settings on Heroku and it now works.